# authenticate from Flex in Django with pyAMF

Tags: django, apache-flex, pyamf

Maybe somebody can show an example of such a task, or specify where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the [example](http://joelhooks.com/2008/09/21/django-authorization-from-flex-air-actionscript-via-pyamf/) given by Joel Hooks.

Comment: Also http://sseetharaman.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/user-authentication-in-django-pyamf-and-flex3-2/ gives a pretty clear walkthrough on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Download [DjangoAMF](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/djangoamf/releases/) for this.

Add the **amf middleware** to middlewares list in **settings.py**.

To authenticate you just have to use **@permission_required** decorator on views from **amf.django**

and add this to your **settings.py**

```
AMF_AUTH_FUNC = 'amf.django.authenticate'
```

Its tested in integrating Flex and DJango. For more details visit, [DjangoAMF](http://djangoamf.sourceforge.jp/index.php?UserManual_en#Install).

Comment: As i know DjangoAMF requerid S2Flex2 flex component, pyAMF can work with native RemoteObject. right ? and i read that DjangoAMF with hundreds of object it started to corrupt data